# Java Socket Can't Connect to Own Computer

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ip

My program works just fine when I do

```
Socket s = new Socket("127.0.0.1", 10000);
```

But when I replace localhost with my own external IP adress, it fails
What gives? It throws an UnknownHostException immediately, even though I can ping my external IP just fine.
Stack trace:

```
java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused: connect
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.doConnect(PlainSocketImpl.java:333)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(PlainSocketImpl.java:195)
        at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:182)
        at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:366)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:529)
        at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:478)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:375)
        at java.net.Socket.<init>(Socket.java:189)
        at FileClient.main(FileClient.java:29)
```

Comment: Being able to ping it doesn't mean the box accepts incoming connections on an arbitrary port. Maybe its firewall is blocking it.

Comment: so, where the heck did you bind you server to? You can bind it on `127.0.0.1` only just as fine...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What gives? It throws an
>   UnknownHostException immediately, even
>   though I can ping my external IP just
>   fine. Stack trace:

I don't see an UnknownHostException in your stack trace. The "remote" side actively refuses the connection. Could be because of a firewall, but unlikely, as firewalls usually silently drop packets instead of actively refusing. Most likely, the server application just isn't listening on the external interface. Most server software behave like that in the default configuration due to security reasons. Check what the output of the `netstat -n -a` command.

Comment: Ok. It turns out it was not listening on the port.

Answer (score 0):

If that's your external IP you would need to open/port forward 100000